# How can I change the return value in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Now,there is a string "hello world"   When I use

```
set("hello world")
```

it returns `{' ','d','e'...}` rather than `{"hello","world"}`

How can I change the return value of set function?

If I need to define a class,what need I to take care?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: It works accoring to specification - you pass a _sequence_ to your `set` function. Your sequence is not a two-element sequence but `len("hello world"`)-element sequence.

Comment: If you want to split your string into words, you could use `set("hello world".split())`. See [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Answer (score 3):

You don't change the return value of the set function. That is built into Python, and you wouldn't want to do it anyway.

You should change what you pass to it:

```
result = set(["hello", "world"])
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks that you want to `split()` your sentence.

So, instead of `set()`:

```
set("hello world")
```

you should use `split()`:

```
"hello world".split(" ")
```

Output:

```
>>> ["hello", "world"]
```

Or maybe even pass this list to `set()`, if this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
set("hello world".split(" "))
```

Comment: Note that `split()` will split on whitespace by default

Comment: "Explicit is better than implicit." - [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3)

Comment: @dot.Py I think `.split()` is more explicit here. He wants set of words, you will get empty strings if there is more than 1 space.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a string to set of its words

```
sentence = "hello world"
wordList = set(sentence.split())

print wordList
```

Output:

```
set(['world', 'hello'])
```

To get a list

```
print list(wordList)
```

Output:

```
['world', 'hello']
```